# Does Crystalline Bonds make its target helpless?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, psionics

The power [Crystalline Bonds](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/psionic-powers/c/crystalline-bonds) "gag[s] and immobiliz[es]" a target.  The target can't take anything but purely mental actions, but the power doesn't actually say that the target is helpless.  The spell is pretty clear that the target can't move or take actions, but it doesn't mention any defensive penalties directly.

It would make sense to me that the target is helpless, since the power description makes me think that it's basically ropes preventing the target from doing anything, but that isn't spelled out.

Is the target effectively helpless when hit with this spell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [SRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Helpless) on the helpless condition:

> A helpless character is paralyzed, held, **bound**, sleeping, unconscious, or otherwise completely at an opponent's mercy.

(emphasis added)

From the SRD ['Tied Up?' sidebar](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#Overrun) (next to the overrun rules):

> A creature that is tied up is "bound" which means it has the Helpless condition.

So I'd go with yes.

Comment: That's my thinking, but "A helpless creature is bound" doesn't necessarily mean the same thing as "A bound creature is helpless".  For example, a creature tied up with rope is pinned, not helpless, according to the grapple rules.

Comment: @DuckTapeAl That's correct, but the list provided does actually correspond to things which yield the helpless condition.  Tied up creatures are helpless and pinned.  I've added a link.